# Better way to create nested array with count equals to children's total count

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

I have input data structure like

```js
const i = [
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 12 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "LBNagar", count: 19 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Koramangala", count: 22 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Koti", count: 10 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 16 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "LBNagar", count: 28 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 11 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Koti", count: 24 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Koramangala", count: 27 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 22 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Manikonda", count: 11 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Manikonda", count: 10 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 17 }
];
```

Expected transformed data structure should be nested array with `count` prop equals to sum of children's `count` value

```js
[
  {
    "d": "Breakfast",
    "count": 42,
    "children": [
      {
        "d": "Bangalore",
        "count": 12,
        "children": [
          {
            "d": "Bellandur",
            "count": 12,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "d": "Hyderabad",
        "count": 30,
        "children": [
          {
            "d": "LBNagar",
            "count": 19,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "d": "Manikonda",
            "count": 11,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "d": "Lunch",
    "count": 91,
    "children": [
      {
        "d": "Bangalore",
        "count": 39,
        "children": [
          {
            "d": "Koramangala",
            "count": 22,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "d": "Bellandur",
            "count": 17,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "d": "Hyderabad",
        "count": 52,
        "children": [
          {
            "d": "LBNagar",
            "count": 28,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "d": "Koti",
            "count": 24,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "d": "Dinner",
    "count": 63,
    "children": [
      {
        "d": "Hyderabad",
        "count": 20,
        "children": [
          {
            "d": "Koti",
            "count": 10,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "d": "Manikonda",
            "count": 10,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "d": "Bangalore",
        "count": 43,
        "children": [
          {
            "d": "Bellandur",
            "count": 16,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "d": "Koramangala",
            "count": 27,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To achieve above result, I have snippet

```js
const input = [
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 12 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "LBNagar", count: 19 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Koramangala", count: 22 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Koti", count: 10 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 16 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "LBNagar", count: 28 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 11 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Koti", count: 24 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Koramangala", count: 27 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 22 },
  { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Manikonda", count: 11 },
  { Time: "Dinner", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Manikonda", count: 10 },
  { Time: "Lunch", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 17 }
];

// convert nested array into map
// Ex: {Breakfast: { Bangalore: {Bellandur: 40 }, ... } ... }}}
const nestedMap = input.reduce((acc, v) => {
  if (!acc[v["Time"]]) {
    acc[v["Time"]] = {};
  }

  if (!acc[v["Time"]][v["City"]]) {
    acc[v["Time"]][v["City"]] = {};
  }

  if (!acc[v["Time"]][v["City"]][v["Area"]]) {
    acc[v["Time"]][v["City"]][v["Area"]] = v["count"];
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const summer = (o, i) =>
  typeof o === "number"
    ? i + o
    : Object.values(o).reduce((acc, v) => acc + summer(v, i), 0);

const aggregator = o => {
  return typeof o === "number"
    ? []
    : Object.entries(o).map(([n, child]) => ({
        d: n,
        count: summer(child, 0),
        children: aggregator(child)
      }));
};

const result = aggregator(nestedMap);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));
```

Thought my snippet working perfectly, It involves lot of iterations. First converting into map and one iteration (`summer` function) to get count of children and other iteration (`aggregator` function) to form nested array.

I am looking for better performant solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a more concise approach with an array of the nested keys and seach for the object with the value at the level.

Then add count and return the actual object.

This approach prevents tailing children arrays

```js
var data = [{ Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 12 }, { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "LBNagar", count: 19 }, { Time: "Lunch", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Koramangala", count: 22 }, { Time: "Dinner", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Koti", count: 10 }, { Time: "Dinner", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 16 }, { Time: "Lunch", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "LBNagar", count: 28 }, { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 11 }, { Time: "Lunch", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Koti", count: 24 }, { Time: "Dinner", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Koramangala", count: 27 }, { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 22 }, { Time: "Breakfast", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Manikonda", count: 11 }, { Time: "Dinner", City: "Hyderabad", Area: "Manikonda", count: 10 }, { Time: "Lunch", City: "Bangalore", Area: "Bellandur", count: 17 }],
    keys = ['Time', 'City', 'Area'],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            keys.reduce((p, k) => {
                var temp = (p.children = p.children || []).find(q => q.d === o[k]);
                if (!temp) p.children.push(temp = { d: o[k], count: 0 });
                temp.count += o.count;
                return temp;
            }, r);
            return r;
        }, { children: [] })
        .children;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```